# $E e^{B_s^2 e^{2B_s}}\mathbb{1}_{\{B_s\leq -1\}} < \infty$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value, brownian-motion

I wan't to see that $E e^{2B_s e^{2B_s}}\mathbb{1}_{\{B_s\leq -1\}} < \infty$ when $B_s\sim N(0,s)$ (standard brownian motion). Any help, please?

Comment: I edited the question. I forgot the indicatrix function. However, I will add more context

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Start by writing out the integral, then bound the integrand.

Comment: I tried to take $\leq $ with the sup and then use Burkholder Davis Gundy inequality, but I don't know how to calculate the quadratic variation.

Comment: $e^{2B_s e^{2B_s}}\mathbb{1}_{\{B_s\leq -1\}}$ is bounded, below by $0$ and above by something less than $1$ so the result follows

Comment: It's the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{-1}1/\sqrt{2\pi s}exp( 2te^t-\frac{t^2}{2s})$. To prove the convergence, show the integral converge with the lower bound to $-\infty$. It's not hard.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea How do you know it's equivalent to this integral?

Comment: @henry maybe it's obvious, but I can't get the upper bound... sorry. I mean, we have the function $f(x) =\exp(x^2 e^{2x})$ with $x\in(-\infty,-1)$, and this means that $f(x) \in (e,\infty)$.

Comment: @Henry $f(x) \in (\exp e^{-2},\infty)$, sorry

Comment: @Rub My reading is $f(x) =\exp(2x e^{2x})$ rather than $f(x) =\exp(x^2 e^{2x})$.  If $x <0$ then $2x e^{2x} <0$ too

Comment: @Henry, well, the question was wrongly edited by other person, sorry. Is a squared. Now is well-written

Comment: OK, so $x^2 e^{2x}$ seems to be no greater than $e^{-2}$ when $x \le -1$ so $\exp(2x e^{2x}) \le e^{e^{-2}} \approx 1.145$ so still bounded above so the expectation is still finite and about $0.1768$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value you are after is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\int_{-\infty}^{-1}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 s}}e^{e^{2x}x^2}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\int_{-\infty}^{-1}e^{-x^2\left(\frac{1}{2 s}-e^{2x}\right)}dx.$$
Now it is easy to show that for some $-\infty<x_0<-1$ we have that $\frac{1}{2 s}-e^{2x}>0$ for all $x<x_0$. And the result you are after follows.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed.